# C++11 templates and callback returns types with void specialization/overloading

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17

This is a bit of a contrived example, but its the least amount of code to reproduce my question.

Here I am passing a function callback, and the result is converted to a string and pushed into a vector. This works great for any type with a `to_string` implementation. (Im using function pointers instead of std::function because some of the function are coming from third party C libraries)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename R>
void Example(std::vector<std::string> &vec, R (*func)()) {
    auto r = func();
    vec.push_back(std::to_string(r));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    Example(vec, static_cast<int(*)()>([]() -> int{
        return 0;
    }));

    Example(vec, static_cast<double(*)()>([]() -> double{
        return 0.0;
    }));
}
```

The one special case however is `void`. In that case I don't want anything pushed to the vector.

```
// This obviously does not compile.
Example(vec, static_cast<void(*)()>([](){
    auto a = 0;
}));
```

I know I can overload `Example`, i.e.

```
void Example(std::vector<std::string> &vec, void (*func)()) {
    func();
}
```

But in my real world application, `Example` is MUCH more complex and overloading results in a lot of copy pasted code. I attempted to use `type_traits` But couldn't get that to work.

Is there another approach that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if constexpr` allows you to conditionally compile code, given that the condition depends on a template parameter. This requires C++17 for `if constexpr` and `#include<type_traits>` for the `std::is_same_v` type trait.

```
template<typename R>
void Example(std::vector<std::string> &vec, R (*func)()) {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<R, void>) {
        func();
    } else {
        auto r = func();
        vec.push_back(std::to_string(r));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly that but without the `constexpr`. I guess I need to study up on 17! Your example did not work for me as is on Mac, but `if constexpr(std::is_void<R>::value)` did. Thanks again!

Comment: @szatmary They should both work with proper C++17 support in the standard library. If it doesn't try `std::is_same<R, void>::value` instead. (Though `std::is_void<R>` does indeed the same here.)

Comment: Hmm. It is working now (I must have had a typeo). thanks again.